# How to apply the CRUD generator for Laravel module architecture?

Tags: php, laravel-5, code-generation, crud, laravel-5.8

I have been created a module in Laravel 5.8 by using the following command.

```
php artisan module:make leave
```

A leave module structure is created. But how can I create a CRUD operation in this module by using the infyom (or another) CRUD generator?

Comment: Laravel does not ship with a `module:make` command.. You can type in the following to see all commands that Laravel ships with: `php artisan list`.

Comment: artisan module:make command is provided by package nWidart/laravel-modules and i assume this package is meant in this question

Comment: Here is discussion about this question (how to use InfyOm CRUD generator with nWidart/laravel-modules plugin for modules): https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/issues/371